# Modification to countif equation

Tags: excel

I’m happy with the equation although wanted to make a tweak, just unsure how to achieve what I’m after…
The equation is the following and it gives the result of the following table:
=(COUNTIFS($B$3:B3,B3,$Z$3:Z3,0)=0)*(COUNTIFS(B:B,B3,U:U,U3<>"",Z:Z,0)=0)

| B (projectID) | U(Project phase/stage) | Z(success=1,non-successful=0 | My new column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 0 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

B: projectID
U: phase of project
Z: success/not for individual projects (0=unsuccessful; or 1 = successful)
new column: success/not for individual projects (taking into account phase of project)

I would like to change it so that it has all the same rules as the above, however if for the same projectID (Column B) and same phase (COLUMN u) and if the FIRST number (column Z) has a value of 0, all the rest of the duplicated values, all values with the same Column B and Column U are the same… Unless: there is a phase before that (with the same projectID) that has a resulting column Z value of 0. This is already incorporated into the equation above

| B | U | Z | My new column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 6 |  | 1 | 0 |
| 6 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 7 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 7 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 7 |  | 0 | 1 |

Any recommendations would be wonderful!!! Thanks

Comment: Can you explain logic why `5,2,1=1` and `5,3,1=0`?

Comment: that new column doesn't 'equal' those other columns... First column is 'projectID' meaning all the projects i have a list of have been assigned a certain number. second column is the project 'phase' ie the stage of a project - It could have stage 1,2,3,4 etc. Third column has been generated from a software (list of 1's  and 0's). These numbers may not make sense in real life cases: because (for example) if a stage 3 project (for a certain projectID)  is unsuccessful, all following stages (4,5,6) should be unsuccessful. The logical behind the newly created column is that, + comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `FILTER()` formula-

```
=@IF(FILTER($C$2:$C$21,($A$2:$A$21=A2)*($B$2:$B$21=1))=0,0,FILTER($C$2:$C$21,($A$2:$A$21=A2)*($B$2:$B$21=B2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In many of the cells in U they are blank spaces. Just wondering how you would deal with that...  Only because i am getting #calc and that may be why

Comment: I added projectID 6 and 7 onto the last table in the explanation so you know what i mean (hopefully i haven't confused!)

Comment: I do not see phase id for project `6` and `7`.

Comment: Oh really, it should just be in the second table in my post - I just added these numbers to the existing table (so right at the end)

Comment: Then can try `=@IF(B2="",FILTER($C$2:$C$30,$A$2:$A$30=A2),IF(FILTER($C$2:$C$30,($A$2:$A$30=A2)*($B$2:$B$30=1))=0,0,FILTER($C$2:$C$30,($A$2:$A$30=A2)*($B$2:$B$30=B2))))`.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Sorry i should have known the above! Really appreciate your help